# Is there any function for sliding window just like in matlab but for python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, sliding-window

I need a function that selects all the data from a 2D array in a square window but I want to do this in Python. Is there any specific function for it?

```
median_x_array = median_coords_3d_array[:, :, 0]  # Extracting x-coordinates
window_size = 3
median_x_neighbors = []
padded_array = np.pad(median_x_array, pad_width = 1, mode = 'wrap')

for i in range(padded_array.shape[0] - window_size + 1):
    for j in range(padded_array.shape[1] - window_size + 1):
        subarray = padded_array[i:i+window_size, j:j+window_size]
        flattened_subarray = subarray.flatten()     
        median_x_neighbors.append(flattened_subarray)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using [numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html). You can set your window view to the shape `(3, 3)` and apply your function across each slice:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view # New import

median_x_array = np.random.rand(10, 10) # an example dummy array
window_size = 3
median_x_neighbors = []
padded_array = np.pad(median_x_array, pad_width = 1, mode = 'wrap')
rolling_views = sliding_window_view(padded_array, (window_size), window_size)) # put a sliding view on top of the array
for i in rolling_views[0, :, :]: # access the views one at a time
    median_x_neighbors.append(i.flatten())
```